# Error while installing Tor

Tags: software-installation, tor

i want to install **development version** of tor following instructions on  https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#development on my ubuntu 14.04 but whenever i run command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

some errors occurs:

```
Err http://deb.torproject.org jessie/main Sources
 404  Not Found [IP: 10.10.34.36 80]
Err http://deb.torproject.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
 404  Not Found [IP: 10.10.34.36 80]
Err http://deb.torproject.org jessie/main i386 Packages
 404  Not Found [IP: 10.10.34.36 80]
Ign http://deb.torproject.org jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://deb.torproject.org jessie/main Translation-en
Fetched 435 kB in 5s (77.3 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch     bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ir.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch     bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ir.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch     bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ir.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 10.10.34.36 80]

W: Failed to fetch     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 10.10.34.36 80]

W: Failed to fetch     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/jessie/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 10.10.34.36 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

after that i run this command

```
sudo apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
```

an error occurs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package deb.torproject.org-keyring
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'deb.torproject.org-keyring'
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: `apt-get update` didn't help?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @Taavi no there are some errors while running this command too.

Comment: @AndroidDev ubuntu 14.04, running cat /etc/debian_version gives me jessie/sid

Comment: Could you write those errors?

Comment: @Taavi yes, i edited the question and include those errors too

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because you followed the Debian Jessie instructions. You need to change the dropdown menu above the instructions to Ubuntu Trusty Tahr. :)

---

You first need to remove the Jessie entries from the depository. To do this enter the below command in Terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-main.list
```

Next you need to update apt:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once you have done that, you will need to continue with the Ubuntu Trusty Tahir instructions.

---

Another way to remove the software sources is to open "Software Centre" using the below icon.

[image]

Within Software Centre click on the "Software and updates" link within the "Ubuntu Software menu" as per below image.

[image]

Within Software and Updates, click on the "Other Software" tab and make sure the 2 options that I've ticked in the below update are removed from your sources. If not, then remove them.

[image]

Once you have done that, close that window and it will update the repository.

Comment: i changed jessie to trusty tahr but didn't work :(

Comment: But in the error message there is seen that `apt-get update` is trying to reach Jessi packages. Make sure that in _/etc/apt/sources_ there are sources for Trusty Tahr and not Jessie

Comment: I have updated my answer with further information.

Comment: From this I assume you're new to Ubuntu. I would recommend either buying a Ubuntu book or search on Youtube for a Ubuntu tutorial. 

Another good source of information is the Ubuntu help page.

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/index.html

Comment: @proprocastinator thanks. yes i'm new to ubuntu but i did all the steps carefully. i think the problem is that my ISP is filtering Torproject.org. can it be the problem?

Comment: I have updated the instructions with a GUI way to remove the sources. Once you have followed the instructions, go through the Tor installation from the beginning, but this time with the Trusty Tahr installation.

Comment: thanks @proprocastinator.  this is a part of the result after running command "sudo apt-get update":    W: Failed to fetch http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 138.201.14.197 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/tor-experimental-0.2.8.x-trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 138.201.14.197 80]

Comment: @proprocastinator i tried to install deb.torproject.org-keyring separately from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/tor/precise/main/base/deb.torproject.org-keyring, but i could'nt find the source package for tor experimental to download and install it.